# Concurrent programming Java Threads

Tags: java, concurrency, java-threads

I have been given a task to do for class however we have only been taught to a certain extent and this has left a knowledge gap. we have been asked to complete the remaining code to some we had done in class, the tutor has given a description of what needs doing but not how, and the time since i last did any independent Java work has been about 7 months so i am a bit rusty below is the code that we wrote with the tutors guidance and further below the description of the task.

```
public class CardHolder implements Runnable {
private int id;
private Account account;
final static int numIterations = 20;

public CardHolder(int id, Account account) {
    this.id = id;
    this.account = account;
}

/*
 * run method is what is executed when you start a Thread that
 * is initialised with an instance of this class.
 * You will need to add code to keep track of local balance (cash
 * in hand) and report this when the thread completes.
 */
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
        // Generate a random amount from 1-10
        int amount = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
        // Then with 50/50 chance, either deposit or withdraw it
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            account.withdraw(id, amount); 
        } else {
            account.deposit(id, amount); 
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    System.out.println("THREAD "+ id + " finished"); 

}
}

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Account {
private String name;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Check to make sure program has been called with correct number of
    // command line arguments
    if (args.length != 3) {
        System.err.println("Error: program should take exactly three command line arguments:");
        System.err.println("\t<No. of accounts> <main acct starting bal.> <backup acct. starting bal.>");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // And then make sure that those args are all integers
    try {
        int numCards = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        Account account = new Account("Main", Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        Account backup = new Account("Backup", Integer.parseInt(args[2]));

        // Your code to create and manage the threads should go here.
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.err.println("All three arguments should be integers");
        System.err.println("\t<No. of accounts> <main acct starting bal.> <backup acct. starting bal.>");
    }
}

// Create an account - initalisation goes in here
public Account(String name, int startingBalance) {
}

// Deposit <amount> into the account
public void deposit(int id, int amount) { 
} 

// Withdraw <amount> from the account
public void withdraw(int id, int amount) {
}  

// Print out the statement of transactions
public void printStatement() {
    System.out.println("Account \"" + name + "\":");
}
}
```

The arguments contained in the run config in eclipse are 50 1000 1000

**The Task**

Many    banking systems allow multiple  cardholders to  access  a   single account (e.g.    a   business
account).   The consequence of  this    is  that    is  possible    for more    than    one person  to  attempt to
withdraw    or  deposit money   from    a   single  account simultaneously. If  the access  to  the 
account is  implemented naïvely (ignoring   the principles  of  concurrent  programming),   this
can lead    to  race    conditions, and the potential   for the following   fraud   to  be  successful:
Multiple    cardholders may collude and attempt to  carry   out a   timing  attack. In  such
an  attack, multiple    cardholders withdraw    money   from    the account simultaneously, 
with    the aim of  only    one deduction   to  the account balance being   made.
Your    task    is  to  write   a   program (detailed   specifications  below)  that    will simulate   the 
operation   of  ATM-enabled linked  bank    accounts with   multiple linked cards.      In  other   words,
there   will    be  several individuals who can access  each account,   each    with    his/her own card    (). 
You program should  demonstrate the principles  of  concurrent  programming,    making  it
impossible  for the above   fraud   to  be  successful

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to reread the chapter in your textbook titled `Locks`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the main thing that you need to worry about is the deposit and withdraw methods.  For example:

```
public class Account {
    public void deposit(int id, int amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }

    public void withdraw(int id, int amount) {
        balance -= amount;
    }

    private int balance;
}
```

The problem with this is that increment/decrement operations may not be atomic.  Under the hood there may be several operations happening, not just one.  For example:

```
int temp1 = balance;
int temp2 = amount;
int temp3 = temp1 - temp2;
balance = temp3;
```

If you have lots of Threads performing this operation at the same time, it could cause results that you don't want.  Try to think about why.  You can avoid this by using the **synchronized keyword**, which forces the entire method to execute atomically.  What I think it does is turn the instance of the class into a **mutex**:

```
public class Account {
    public synchronized void deposit(int id, int amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }

    public synchronized void withdraw(int id, int amount) {
        balance -= amount;
    }

    private int balance;
}
```

In order to test this, I wouldn't use a Random, because it is not **deterministic**.  What I would do is launch say, 1000 threads to perform a specific number of withdrawals concurrently.  If you have a balance of $1,000,000, and you launch 1000 threads to withdraw $1 over and over 1000 times, you should have $0 in the account after the test.  Try to simulate the wrong answer before you add the synchronized keyword, and verify that it is fixed by adding the synchronized keyword.